# Transform XML into Markdown format text

Tags: java, markdown

I'm trying to transform an XML into a Markdown

```
public static Document transformXmlToMarkdown(String xml) throws TransformerException {
    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
    TransformerFactory tFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    Transformer transform = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(markdown)));
    transform.transform(source, result);
    return (Document) result.getNode();
}
```

The `markdown` in the `new StringReader(markdown)` is based [here](https://github.com/bauhouse/xslt-markdown/blob/master/markdown.xsl).
The problem with this code is that I does not transform.

The input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<en-note>
    <div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <en-media hash="" type="application/octet-stream"/>
    <div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div>This is my first Evernote blog with image/photo attached.</div>
    <div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div>This is another line. </div>
    <div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div>Some 
        <i>formatting </i>also for 
        <b>some </b>lines. 
    </div>
</en-note>
```

Output should be:

```
This is my first Evernote blog with image/photo attached.



This is another line.



Some _formatting_ also for **some** lines.
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Also tested with https://www.getsymphony.com/download/xslt-utilities/source-code/20573/

Answer (score 1):

The xslt script you referring to can be used to convert some kind of HTML to Markdown.

Your XML is not HTML. Your XML starts with a root element "en-note" and there is no match on that in the XSLT, so no processing of that element.